# ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN cannot run inside a transaction block;

Tags: redshift

I am trying to alter column in redshift from `varchar(30)` to `varchar(100)` Its not working and throwing an error as below:

Command used:

```
alter table t_name alter column c1 type varchar(300);
```

Error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN cannot run inside a transaction block; [SQL State=25001, DB Errorcode=500310]
```

Comment: Well, then don't do it inside a transaction. What exactly is your question?

Comment: To be fair to the OP, I came to this post after searching this error because in the past I have run ALTER TABLE commands inside a transaction block without issue, but created a seemingly simple script on another instance that threw this error with no additional detail

Answer (score 1):

This Helped me

```
set autocommit on;
alter table schemaname.tablename alter column columnname type varchar(2000);
set autocommit off;
```

[Solution Found Here](https://awsbytes.com/alter-table-alter-column-cannot-run-inside-a-transaction-block/)

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html), check if you are violating any conditions:

> `ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type` - A clause that changes the
> size of a column defined as a `VARCHAR` data type. Consider the
> following limitations:
>
> - You can't alter a column with compression encodings `BYTEDICT`,
>   `RUNLENGTH`, `TEXT255`, or `TEXT32K`.
> - You can't decrease the size less than maximum size of existing data.
> - You can't alter columns with default values.
> - You can't alter columns with `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, or `FOREIGN KEY`.
> - You can't alter columns within a transaction block (`BEGIN ... END`).
>   For more information about transactions, see [Serializable isolation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html).